# How to read Lua table return value from C++

Tags: c++, lua, lua-table

I have a Lua function that returns table (contains set of strings)
the function run fine using this code:

```
lua_pushstring (lua, "funcname");  
lua_gettable   (lua, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX);
lua_pushstring(lua, "someparam");
lua_pcall (lua, 1, 1, 0);
```

the function returns a table. How do I read it's contents from my C++ code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are asking how to traverse the resulting table, you need [lua_next](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_next) (the link also contains an example). As *egarcia* said, if `lua_pcall` returns 0, the table the function returned can be found on top of the stack.

Comment: `lua_next()` will enumerate all of contents of the table, however, it may be easier to directly access the table if the index is known. `lua_gettable()`, `lua_getfield()`, `lua_rawget()`, or `lua_rawgeti()` can all access the contents of a table if an index is known.

Comment: @gwell: true, but given that OP used `lua_gettable` in his sample, I assumed he already knows about some of those at least.

Answer (score 1):

If the function doesn't throw any errors, then lua_pcall will:

1. Remove the parameters from the stack
2. Push the result to the stack

This means that, if your function doesn't throw any errors, you can use lua_setfield right away - `lua_pcall` will work just like [lua_call](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_call):

```
lua_pushstring (lua, "funcname");  
lua_gettable   (lua, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX);
lua_pushstring(lua, "someparam");
lua_pcall (lua, 1, 1, 0);
lua_setfield(L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "a");        /* set global 'a' */
```

would be the equivalent of:

```
a = funcname(someparam)
```

Comment: Assigning the table to a global is not exactly the same as reading its contents.