# Accessing a Lua table within a table from C++

Tags: c++, lua

I have a Lua function that returns a dictionary table, and one of the values that's put into the returned table is another table as demonstrated in the following Lua function.

```
function tableWithinTable()
    local ret = {}
    ret["a"] = 1
    ret["b"] = {1,2,3}
    ret["c"] = 3
    return ret
end
```

How would I go about accessing that inner table?

I know I can get to the table, because I can enter the following if statement. My current attempt at reading the table is included as well.

```
lua_pushstring("b");
lua_gettable(lua,1);
if(lua_istable(lua,-1))
{
    //whatever is in here is executed.
    lua_pushnumber(lua,1);
    lua_gettable(lua,-1); //crashes to desktop here
    std::cout << lua_tonumber(lua,-1) << std::endl;
    lua_pop(lua,1);
}
```

I'm pretty sure there's an easy solution to this, but I'm totally stumped. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running in a debugger? Also, how is `lua` declared and initialized in your C++ code?

Comment: Here is a bit of checking types on the stack http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2002-11/msg00104.html and here is an example that talks about stack pop http://www.gamedev.net/topic/332365-lua-get-table-content/ finally check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970021/how-to-read-lua-table-return-value-from-c

Comment: And actually this article, http://forum.gpwiki.org/viewtopic.php?t=9106 seems to be exactly what you want.

Comment: smocking - yes, still just crashes to desktop. lua is the active lua_State created by lua_open().

Comment: Richard Chambers - I'll check it out, seems to be exactly what I need though. Thanks!

Comment: There is no way you enter that `if` statement. You push a string, and then ask if the string is a table. That will never be true. So odds are good that this *isn't* your actual code, or you're getting other problems.

Comment: Nicol Bolas - you're right, I forgot a line after the lua_pushstring.
There should be a 'lua_gettable(lua,1);' right before the if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you push the index, the table is one more slot away in the stack.  So something like this should work:

```
if(lua_istable(lua,-1)) {
  lua_pushnumber(lua,1);
  lua_gettable(lua,-2);
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is generally easier to use functions `lua_getfield` (for string indexes) or `lua_rawgeti` (for numerical indexes) than the raw `lua_gettable` function.

In particular, that avoids the extra value on the stack that causes your indexing error.

The example could be rewritten as :

```
lua_getfield(lua, 1, "b");
if(lua_istable(lua, -1))
{
    lua_rawgeti(lua, -1, 1);
    std::cout << lua_tonumber(lua,-1) << std::endl;
    lua_pop(lua, 1);
}
```